# Oracle cannot use IMGSilimar for ORDImage

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, psql

I have the following procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIND_SIMILAR_PICTURES
( nazwa in varchar, exp in varchar)
IS
  idk number(10);
  img_score number;
  image ORDSYS.ORDImage;
  query_sig ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature;
  text varchar(200) := 'shape="1.0"';
  CURSOR photos IS SELECT idk, IMGScore(1), obrazek FROM foto_oferty WHERE ORDSYS.IMGSimilar(image_sig,query_sig,text,10,1) = 1;
BEGIN
  SELECT image_sig INTO query_sig FROM foto_oferty WHERE nazwa_pliku = nazwa;
  OPEN photos;
    LOOP
      FETCH photos INTO idk, img_score, image;
      EXIT WHEN photos%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Obrazek z id '||idk||'pasuje.');
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE photos;
END;
```

Structure of table.

```
CREATE TABLE foto_oferty(
  idk number(10) NOT NULL,
  nazwa_pliku varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  obrazek ORDimage,
  modyf ORDimage,
  oferta_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  image_sig ORDImageSignature,
  CONSTRAINT foto_oferty_pk PRIMARY KEY(idk)
);
```

When I run this procedure I get that error.

```
Error(9,76): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ORDSYS"."IMGSIMILAR": invalid identifier
```

Is it the problem that I don't use properly method IMGSimilar?

Comment: One would venture to guess you are really trying to execute a procedure within a package in which case the proper format would be of the form [SCHEMA].[PACKAGE].[PROCEDURE()]

Comment: @Stilgar Can you present example of this?

Comment: @Stilgar I used Maciek.ORDSYS.IMGSimilar and the error message is the same. Maciek is schema name which I use.

Comment: SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000).  Where schema (owner) = "SYS" and "DBMS_OUTPUT" is the package and "ENABLE" is the procedure.  I cannot provide an example for this IGMSimilar procedure you are trying to invoke as I do not have access to that here; and part of your problem may be that you do not have privileges on that object in your database either.

Comment: @Stilgar, So better give all privelleges to user which fires this procedure.

Comment: ORDSYS would be the schema, not Maciek.  ORDSYS would be the owner of the object you are trying to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should think the following query would tell you if your object exists and is visible to you

```
SELECT
     *
FROM all_procedures
WHERE owner = 'ORDSYS'
  AND
    (
        (procedure_name LIKE '%IMG%')
    OR
        (procedure_name LIKE '%SIM%')
    )
ORDER BY all_procedures.procedure_name
;
```

If the object is available you can find entry points in the schema browser of whichever SQL tool you are using.

Comment: I have checked this procedure is not avaiable. Even logged as sysdba I don't see that procedure.

Comment: Did you look for procedure or for a procedure within a package?

Comment: I have looked for the procedure IMGSilimar. I wanted to test an example from there http://pages.di.unipi.it/ghelli/didattica/bdldoc/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14297/ch_imgref.htm#BABIDHDE

Comment: I see.  I do not know of this product so I do not know if it is part of Oracle's standard package or if it requires extended license.  But if YOU can't see it via query or schema browser then it either doesn't exist or you don't have privileges on it.  And that would explain the ORA-00904.

Comment: I will try to use IsSimilary which is avaiable.